# Error during template rendering (Django)

Tags: python, django, шаблоны, обработка-ошибок

Привет всем, недавно ознакомился с офф документацией по django и решил освоить удаление данных из бд методом POST ( Знаю, что в django есть такая вещь как Form, но хочу попробовать сперва сделать это сам).
Собственно при загрузке страницы получаю следуюшию ошибку:

> Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$delete/$']

Вот содержание:
**views.py**
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
    from .models import News

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your views here.

def news(request):
    listNews =  News.objects.all()
    context = {'listNews': listNews}
    return render(request, 'news/index.html', context)

def delete(request):
    delNews = request.POST['news']
    d = News.objects.filter(id=delNews).delete()
    return reverse('news:delete', kwargs={'news.id'})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name='news'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.news, name='news'),
    url(r'^delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
]
```

**index.html**

```
{% if listNews %}
<form action="{% url 'news:delete' news.id %}" method="post">
{% for news in listNews %}
{% csrf_token %}
    <h4>{{news.title}}</h4>
    {{news.text}}
    {{news.author}}
    {{news.date}}
    <input type="text" name="news" id="news{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ news.id }}" />
    <input type="submit" />
{% endfor %}
</form>
<p>No news avaliable</p>
{% endif %}
```

P.S. Я осознаю, что здесь могут содержаться ошибки и другого рода, был бы очень признателен, если бы вы мне помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь, но я решил переписать код:
Может кому-нибудь пригодится
**views.py** :

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import News

# Create your views here.

def news(request):
    listNews =  News.objects.all()
    context = {'listNews': listNews}
    return render(request, 'news/index.html', context)

def delete(request, news_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            emp = News.objects.get(pk = news_id)
            emp.delete()
            return HttpResponse('deleted')
```

**index.html:**

```
{% for news in listNews %}
    <h4>{{news.title}}</h4>
    {{news.text}}
    {{news.author}}
    {{news.date}}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action='delete/{{news.id}}/' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" >
    </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py в проекте news**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name='news'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.news, name='news'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<news_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
]
```

**основной urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    **url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),**
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ссылка в form action хочет строиться с использованием news.id, а в урле этого нет.

Тег url строит ссылки исходя из тех строк что у вас написаны в urls.py.

Уберите `news.id` из строки `{% url 'news:delete' news.id %}`

Comment: убрал, но ошибка всё равно осталась.

Comment: А покажи как у тебя подключается этот urls.py. А то в формировании url используется namespace news:. Может система просто не видит это пространство имен?

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
 url(r'^$', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] <- вот urls в корневой папке

Comment: url(r'^$', include('news.urls'), namespace="news") - попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но я решил переписать код.